# Deconstructing piped (exiftool & imagemagick) bash command into individual commands

Tags: node.js, bash, imagemagick, exiftool

I have a working bash script which extracts raw data from an image. I'm converting this script into JS (node.js) and am having trouble converting a piped command into its components to translate into javascript. The exiftool command works (as far as I can tell, and the error occurs at the first convert function.

Working bash pipe:

```
exiftool $F -b -RawThermalImage | convert - gray:- | convert -depth 16 -endian lsb -size $Resolution gray:- $F-RAW.tiff
```

Current (not working) javascript:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const exiftool = require('dist-exiftool');
const im = require('imagemagick');

execFile(exiftool, ['file.jpg', '-b', '-RawThermalImage', '-w', '-raw.jpg'], (error) => {
    if (err) throw "Error extracting RawThermalImage. Unsupported filetype.";

    im.convert(['file-raw.jpg', 'gray', 'file-raw.jpg'], function(err, stdout){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('stdout:', stdout);

        im.convert(['file-raw.jpg', '-depth', '16', 'endian', 'lsb', '-size', resolution, 'gray', 'file-raw.jpg'], function(err, stdout){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('stdout:', stdout);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In your second command, try `im.convert(['raw-file.jpg',  'gray:raw-file.gray']... Then pass raw-file.gray to your third command. See gray at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported

Comment: @fmw42 unfortunately, while the command `convert raw.tiff gray:raw.gray` works on command line, `im.convert(['raw.tiff', 'raw.gray']... ` and `im.convert(['raw.tiff', 'gray:-']... ` both fail for me in node

Comment: `im.convert(['raw.tiff', 'gray:raw.gray']...` also fails

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Node.js. So I cannot help further

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with Azure and not with Nodejs.
`im.convert(['raw.tiff', 'gray:raw.gray']...` works perfectly. For anyone having this issue with Azure imagemagick not working, the only distribution that working in Azure functions is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-imagemagick). Thanks to @fmw42